# Using 'it' in sentences with indefinite noun phrases

Tags: english, semantics, pronouns, nouns

I was looking at indefinite noun phrases like 'a man' or specifically sentences of this form:

'If I were to bring a chicken home, my dog would try to eat it.

Why is it that 'a chicken' does not refer, yet we can later use 'it' to refer to the chicken that I would have bought home?

I understand giving a 'description' of what I could bring home, yet why can I use 'it' like a reference to something that I have not referenced?

I understand it is a requirement to speak of things in generality, but why can we do this?

Comment: _A chicken_ introduces the animal into the discourse; once introduced, it is known material and can be referenced as such. You can even reference it before introducing it if you switch the clauses (“My dog would try to eat it if I brought home a chicken”), as long as the introduction is close enough.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet does the fact there is no 'real' chicken affect anything, the fact it could be any chicken, and there is no 'denotation' of a real thing? When I begin saying 'the dog will eat it' do I introduce it as a hypothetical chicken?

Comment: No, the fact that the situation is hypothetical makes no difference – hypothetical chickens are just as real as real chickens in terms of their availability as discourse material. In the cataphoric example, you’re creating an expectation in the listener’s mind that some discourse element will be referred to – a ‘slot’, as it were, which the listener then fills in with either an existing discourse element or the introduction of a new one.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ok that makes sense thank you

Comment: One of Postal's _Linguistic Anarchy Notes_ concerns an alligator whose tail fell off, though it grew back. Postal goes on to give (iirc) the following example: _His house burned to the ground, but he rebuilt it_. Exactly what kind of reference do we have here? (incidentally, Postal's notes are in [_Notes from the Linguistic Underground_](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Notes_from_the_Linguistic_Underground/0RGMzgEACAAJ?hl=en))

Comment: @jlawler can you have cataphora for references that do not necessarily refer? Or do they begin to refer later? For example some would say 'she needs a man to fix the drain' does not have a denoting phrase in it, I'm not sure where we can see these as denoting or not?

Comment: @jlawler What about 'I met the current King of France, and I liked him', how can we use 'him' later when 'current king of france' should not refer?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by _denote_ and _denoting_ (adj). _Denotations_ in the philosophical sense are not ostensive phenomena -- you can't discover them or observe them. They're entirely technical terms in technical formal systems that depend on their definitions and axioms, not on any observational data.

Comment: @Confused Well, if the sentence is false, who cares what the reference is? From a false premise any desired conclusion can be reached. [That's the result of the last two lines in the truth table for material implication.](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: Oh, one other thing -- there is a difference between definite descriptions and indefinite descriptions. _A man to fix the plumbing_ contains one non-specific NP, _a man_, and one definite NP, _the plumbing_. Both refer, but in different ways. Non-specific indefinite NPs contrast with specific NPs; _I saw a policeman_ is specific, but _I need a policeman_ is non-specific, though they both refer. Definiteness is not the same as denotation, specificity, or reference.

Comment: @jlawler I appreciate your response, my issue is that if this dog is non existent, so we 'refer' but not in specifics? What are we referring to, no specific object? Can you refer without having a specific thing to refer to in mind? If we can do this, do co-refferences work for this?

Comment: Ask a religious person what "God" or "god" refers to. Don't ask me.

Comment: @jlawler you make a point

Answer (score 3):

Noun phrases don't have to refer to entities *in the real world*. This is why a phrase like "a unicorn" can still make sense, when unicorns do not exist in the real world.

"A chicken" here refers to a hypothetical chicken, in the fictional world of an if-then clause.

Comment: I guess my issue is 'if I had a chicken' is so indeterminate it almost seems like theres no *particular* hypothetical chicken either, it could be *any* chicken, but at the same time we could say 'it' is *whichever* chicken I bring.

Comment: @Confused Exactly, it's the one particular hypothetical chicken that you decided to bring home in this fantasy.